# fetching two elements instead of one

Tags: php

the table looks like this:

id -- questions -- test_name

1  --  Number 1 --  Prelim

2  --  Number 2 -- Prelim

3  --  Number 3 -- Prelim

4  --  Number 4 -- Prelim

1  --  Number 1 -- Midterm

2  --  Number 2 -- Midterm

3  --  Number 3 -- Midterm

4  --  Number 4 -- Midterm

first, the tables in the database where the id is not auto-incremented but instead for every major exams (prelim, midterm) the id is repeated as 1,2,3,4 which is equivalent to the number of questions per major exams.

the problem is that when we fetch only 1 element, let's say for PRELIM, with id = "1", the Midterm with id= "1" also appears. how do I omit the midterm?

the query code:

```
    $id=$_GET['id'];

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM paper WHERE id = '$id' and test_name='$test_name'");
```

I hope u understand my problem.

[image]

Comment: I'll look at solving this in a second, but you should really sanitize $id before running it in a query or you're going to be in a world of hurt.

Comment: That's really not a great database design. You should not have duplicate values for `id`.

Comment: Convention is that 'id' is the col for the unique autoincrement key. You'd better change the name of 'id' for other keyword.

Answer (score 0):

As lonesomeday says in comments I dont think this is great design but you can use the IS NOT functionality instead of what you have now, assuming that test_name holds the value you're looking for.

```
 $id=mysql_escape_string($_GET['id']);
 $test_name = 'PRELIM';     
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM paper WHERE id = '$id' and test_name IS NOT '$test_name'");
```

Otherwise you'll need to post what your full table is for us to take a look.  Also keep in mind mysql_escape_string is depreciated, but it's better than nothing :)